# Frameworks for dynamically managing images in-browser in .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, image-processing

Let me first explain what I am trying to achieve... I would like to develop a website that offers some product. This product consists of multiple parts (for example, say a car). The user selects different parts and an image is generated dynamically to preview what the product would look like.

I know how to set the website up, manage database connections, and do all of that. My question is simple: Is there an existing framework that would help me to manage the manipulation of the images easily? My intention is to have separate images of each part and to overlay them in a determined fashion to develop the full product.

I think this would be possible with some fancy manipulation of the basic image controls, but I thought I would see if there was anything to make my job easier. I haven't done much with images in .NET so I don't really know what is available to me as of yet. I am experienced with images in C++ and C.

Note: This is only for research purposes, I am not developing this for any client or job. I just want to see how to do it. I am open to using regular .NET or MVC, depending on which would be most helpful for this.

Thank you for any help that you can offer.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, *software library*, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I did not specify a software library. While a framework can be a software library, it technically means a basic structure underlying a system or concept. That is what I am looking for: basic structures, theoretical or actual, underlying the concept of dynamic image manipulation. This could include techniques that I am unaware of.

Comment: The end result is a software library. If you're asking generically "how do I do this" the answer is write code to do it or find someone who has already written the code. Either way, it's off-topic.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I believe you misunderstand what I am asking for. Either way, I concede to your point. Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a full image of the car but have specific segments which you can identify through code. So your full image can be an "Image Sprite" and then you can show/hide specific chunks as the user is selecting/deselecting those segments. [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp) is an example that uses CSS to show specific parts of a full image. In that example, the images are separated using CSS, but you would not do that for your case. You would simply hide or show them.

Comment: I didn't know that this existed. I think I will find it useful. Thank you!